# How do I migrate mavenRepo in Gradle 1.7 to maven in Gradle 1.9?

Tags: maven, gradle

In build scripts for Gradle 1.7, it's common to see

```
mavenRepo url: 'https://artifactory.example.com/repo'
```

However, after upgrading to Gradle 1.9, running `gradle` yields the following warning:

```
The RepositoryHandler.mavenRepo() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please use the maven() method instead.
```

A quick look in the [Gradle docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler.html) confirms that `mavenRepo` has been deprecated. How should I migrate from `mavenRepo` to `maven`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The documentation for the Gradle DSL indicates that `maven` accepts a closure or an action. After some minutes of digging, I found an example that works as follows.

```groovy
maven {
  url 'https://artifactory.example.com/repo'
}
```